# Excel Dropdown selected value not displayed after save and reopen

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet which uses a button to allow users to add new resources to a list. When the button is clicked, a row is inserted above it and a dropdown is created in the first cell of that row with various resource types. The rows and dropdowns are being created successfully, however if you select the resource types for all of the added rows and then save an exit the workbook, the selections are not displayed when the sheet is re-opened. If another resource row is added, all the drop down selections re-appear. Also, if the drop down box itself is moved at all, the select will re-appear.

On top of that, this does not happen with ever selection. **If** the first drop down option is selected, it is displayed upon re-opening.

All of the combo boxes have a linked cells, and it is being saved as a Macro enabled work book. I cannot think of why they would not be displayed - anyone have any ideas?

---UPDATE---

How the Drop down is being created:

```
Set curCombo = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, Left:=Cells(cs, 1).Left, Top:=Cells(cs, 1).Top, Width:=110, Height:=16)
With curCombo
    .ControlFormat.DropDownLines = 4
    .ControlFormat.AddItem "Labor - Engineer"
    .ControlFormat.AddItem "Labor - Technician"
    .ControlFormat.AddItem "Labor - Support"
    .ControlFormat.AddItem "Shop"
    .Name = "resource_" & cs & "_comboBx"
End With

ActiveSheet.DropDowns("resource_" & cs & "_comboBx").LinkedCell = Cells(cs, 1).Address
```

Comment: Would you be able to share the code you used? I am assuming you used the data validation function to create the drop-down menu.

Comment: sure can. I did not use the data validation function, I am new to VBA and mainly self taught so there is a good chance that I did not use the best practice so any input would be GREATLY appreciated. I will add the code to the original post right now

Comment: Works for me - created 100 drop-downs and on save/re-open they displayed as expected.

Comment: It works on all of my other sheets as well, but this one sheet has this anomaly. The drop downs are being created the same way, with the exception of the items being added by a loop rather than individually